# Commenting system on posts using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, forms

This is my code where I pass the `comment` and the post id (hidden input tag) to another php file `comments.php` which should insert it into db and show the result but its not happening.

This is my form - part of code quoted in echo...I have an auto increment `pid` associated with each post so for every comment, the `comment` and the `pid` are stored in the database:

```
<form  method=\"POST\" onSubmit=\"comment(); return false;\">
    <input  id=\"comment\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Add Comment...\" name=\"comment\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pid\" value=\"".$row['pid']."\">
    <div class=\"z\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" ></div>
</form>
```

JavaScript - a function `comment()` is called for each post's comment form using `onsubmit`.

```
function comment() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "comments.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#".$row['pid']).html(data);
        },
        error:function (){
        }
    });
}
```

This is the `comments.php` code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'db.php';

    $j =$_POST['comment'];
    $k = $_POST['pid'];
    $l =$_SESSION['uname'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (pid,name,comment) values     ('$k','$l','$j')";
    $r = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $r->execute();
    if($r) {
        echo '<div class="comment">
                  <a class="avatar">
                      <img style="height:30px;"src="zmf.jpg">
                  </a>
                  <div class="content">
                      <a class="author">'.$l.'</a>
                      <div class="metadata">
                          <span class="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="text">';
                          echo   $j.'</div>
                      <div class="actions">

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          ';
  }
?>
```

What `comments.php` should return would be shown in the `div` in the `index.php` having an `id = #postid` which is already assigned in that index.php for each post:

```
<div id=\"".$row['pid']."\">
</div>
```

`index.php` has such a `div` for each post so the post on which a comment is done, comment will be shown in that `div` placed below each post. Any help would be appreciated.

i run two while loop to show all previuos comments for each post like this.
first loop shows post and a nested while loop with each post that shows comment on each post..and a comment form for each post in while loop along with a div having an id = postid to show the ajax result..

```
    $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY pid DESC");
    $q->execute();

      while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 #my post in div 
 #comment form
   <form  method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"comment()\">
    <input  id=\"comment\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Add Comment...\" name=\"comment\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pid\" value=\"".$row['pid']."\">
    <div class=\"z\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" ></div>
</form>
        #div where recent comment is shown using ajax
    <div id=\"".$row['pid']."\">
      </div>

 #nested while loop for comments

$zmf = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE pid = '" . $row['pid'] . "' ORDER BY                        comid DESC";
    $zed = $conn->prepare($zmf);
     $zed->execute();
      $run = $zed->fetch();
     while($run = $zed->fetch())
    {
     my div code and all..for comments
   }

     }
```

every post has an id pid ..
but its nt working ..plz help

Comment: Can you show the complete script where you activate the `comment()` in your javascript?

Comment: thats the only js part i have in my file..what else?

Comment: Oh, sorry I see what you have done, you have it inline. Ok disregard!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have multiple `<form>` elements on the page? If so, try changing `$('form').serialize()` to `$(this).serialize()`.

Can you provide a little more information on what result you are getting? Are you seeing any entry in the database? What is the output that you are seeing in the div, after the ajax request?

Are you using PDO? Add an else condition to your `if($r)` check and add `print_r($r->errorInfo())`. Try enabling the developer tools panel in Chrome / Firebug in Firefox and check the result of the ajax (XHR) request. If the sql query is failing, it might raise a `PDOException`. Ensure that the XHR request is returning `200 OK` http status.

Try the following code and post the output

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

$j = $_POST['comment'];
$k = $_POST['pid'];
$l = $_SESSION['uname'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (pid,name,comment) values     ('$k','$l','$j')";

print_r($_POST);

try {
    $r = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $r->execute();
    if ($r) {
        echo '<div class="comment">
                    <a class="avatar">
                        <img style="height:30px;"src="zmf.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a class="author">' . $l . '</a>
                        <div class="metadata">
                            <span class="date">Today at 5:42PM</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">' . $j . '</div>
                        <div class="actions">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
    } else {
        print_r($r->errorInfo());
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Comment: Is there an online version, which I can check?

Comment: no..no insertion in database but i think it should do..m using pdo

Comment: and no result in div too

Comment: i m working on localhost..there is no online version..can i send you the code on email ?

Comment: after changine code with your code..the url has changed form http://localhost/index.php to http://localhost/index.php?comment=jn&pid=102&submit=Submit

Comment: its taking comment, pid as POST but still not showing result

Comment: If the URL changed, it means the javascript did not execute and intercept the form submission. It can't be caused by my changes, since the code in `comments.php` is not executed up to then.

Comment: but no insertion in database ..i think its not transferring control to comments.php..plz tell if u can..ohh sorry actually i removed method="POST" from <form> tag..thats why it s showing submit in url...not bcz of ur changes

Comment: Replace `<form  method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"comment()\">` with `<form  method=\"POST\" onsubmit=\"comment()\" action=\"comments.php\">` and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115271/discussion-between-zaki-mustafa-and-joyce-babu).