# form submission using ajax-jquery and stopping the normal html submission

Tags: ajax

i am working on a html form where i am using a jquery ajax function that is called in the  tag with onSubmit but the problem is that when user presses submit button or enter, the form gets submitted and page gets refreshed and the ajax function is not executed resulting in an output that is undesired.
How can i stop the normal submission and make the form submission only using ajax function and why the ajax function is not getting executed..i even tried .submit attribute of jquery but nithing happened.
please suggest some hacks/methods to deal with it. thanks

Comment: You need to share your code html/js.

Comment: gevorg..i used the same ajax function for an input tag using onBlur and it worked fine..now when i am using it for a form with onSubmit its not working..so i know my code is fine but i just want to stop that html form submission and do it oonly using ajax-jquery..i m trying to post the code

Comment: in that case just `return false` in your `onSubmit` method and it will cancel regular submission.

Comment: i did that too but its not happening..the page gets refreshed instead of calling the js function..can the code be shared in comments secttion??

Comment: Just include it in your question or share it in jsfiddle.net and past the link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959087/commenting-system-on-posts-using-ajax-and-php

Comment: this is the link of the question that i asked ..it has complete code please see this

Comment: You just need to return it in proper way, look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default behaviour of the submit event by using

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This could be find in the JQuery documentation https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: i did that too..and the page is getting refreshed...i

Comment: Well, you should show your code if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959087/commenting-system-on-posts-using-ajax-and-php..

Answer (score 0):

To disable form submission change your code to following:

```html
<form action="/"  method="POST" onSubmit="return comment();">
    ...
</form>
```

```js
function comment() {
   ...
   return false;
}
```

Working sample is here https://jsfiddle.net/gevorgha/5dyc2ye9/ , try changing  `return false;` to `return true;` and you will see submission.

Comment: @Zaki Mustafa, did it work for you? If yes makes sense to accept this as answer.